# Names of all the keymaps for multilanguage remapping purposes

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, input-method, keyboard-layout

How do I extract the names for all of the keymaps in Emacs?

I use English layout for programming.   However I sometimes have to use a Hungarian layout, and I want preserve my keybindings in a physical form, not a symbolic one.  I find `quail` rather uncomfortable, because it is impossible to make a perfect transition: there are more characters in the Hungarian layout than the English one.

Instead of converting the OS configured English layout characters to Hungarian inside Emacs, I want to translate all of the keymaps to the physical layout of a Hungarian keyboard.

Hopefully, I can write an elisp script for that.  However, what I do not know is: how do I extract all of the global, minor, and major mode keymaps from Emacs?

Comment: The function `current-active-maps` can be of some help but it is not the full answer (because it only gives currently active maps, as its name implies).

Comment: (The above comment of mine was initially an answer. Someone decided that it should be a comment instead, so now I can't edit it. Here's some more information, still.)
`current-active-keymaps` doens't give you the name of the keymap, but even though you asked for names (in the first part of your question), they are not actually required for doing what you want (which is rebinding keys).

Comment: I now realize that the initial question to which I was answering did *not* mention names at all, which might very well be why I didn't mention them in my first answer? @Dan Why did you introduce keymap *names* in your edit ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is flawed:

1. A keymap does *not* necessarily have a name.  A keymap can be a *list* - see the Elisp manual, node [Format of Keymaps](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Format-of-Keymaps.html) - and there need not be any name associated with the list.
2. For those keymaps that might be said to "have a name", there are two different meanings:

   - Symbols whose `symbol-value` is a keymap (i.e., keymap *variables*).
     For these, you can use:

     ```
     (mapatoms (lambda (m) (and (boundp m)  (keymapp (symbol-value m))))
               obarray)
     ```
   - Symbols whose `symbol-function` is a keymap (so the symbol itself is also a keymap).
     For these you can use just `(mapatoms #'keymapp obarray)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that will extract all of the keymaps from the [global `obarray`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html):

```
(defun get-all-the-keymaps ()
  "Return list of all the keymaps in the global obarray."
  (let (maps)
    (mapatoms (lambda (x)
                (when (keymapp x)
                  (push x maps)))
              obarray)
    maps))
```

Here's another version that uses the heuristic that any symbol ending in `...-map` is a keymap:

```
(defun really-get-all-the-keymaps ()
  "Return list of all the keymaps in the global obarray."
  (let (maps)
    (mapatoms (lambda (x)
                (when (string-match ".*-map$" (symbol-name x))
                  (push x maps)))
              obarray)
    maps))
```

Just a heads-up: there's a lot of maps.  For example, running it on my machine returns 90 keymaps with the first function, and 624 with the second.

Comment: Many symbols will not satisfy `keymapp` but their value will, so you may want to test `(or (keymapp x) (keymapp (symbol-value x)))` instead.

Comment: @YoungFrog: throws a bunch of errors, sorry.  I've edited the post with another, more permissive function that returns anything ending in `...-map`.

Comment: @YoungFrog: Wrt the second definition given: You cannot tell whether a symbol has any relation to a keymap by whether its `symbol-name` ends in `-map`, and certainly not that it "names" a keymap.

Comment: @Dan Oh yeah you have to test for `(boundp x)` too before taking `symbol-value`. Drew gave some code in his answer.

Comment: @Drew I think you meant to write to Dan.

Comment: @YoungFrog: Sorry, I thought it was you who added the second code snippet.